# how decode the encodeBase64URLSafeString hashkey

Tags: java, spring, encryption, base64, jasypt

How to decode the encoded string using encodeBase64URLSafeString.

code:
`KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("HmacSHA1");`

`SecretKey key = generator.generateKey();`

`encodedKey = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(key.getEncoded());`

`output:`
`E6S9fTfMfAgkNVodHLDmxz-2M_g90bpFztW6GB7-7VcGfyOkugESxjNx1CGf5taJDXz895uWAF5ubPnaqhe4nw`

can anyone please help me on how to decode the output string which is in encrypted format?

Tried using decryption with jasypt library but it is throwing bad input error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to decode it with the same library you have used for encoding `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;`

This is working for me

```
System.out.println(Base64.decodeBase64("E6S9fTfMfAgkNVodHLDmxz-2M_g90bpFztW6GB7-7VcGfyOkugESxjNx1CGf5taJDXz895uWAF5ubPnaqhe4nw"));
```

[image]

Keep in mind **Decode/Decrypt** are 2 different things. Here you have encoded it, in your last process, so you have to decode it.

Comment: It worked,thanks @Panagiotis Bougioukos for the help

Comment: @saipothuri please accept the answer if it has helped you solve the problem